# Batch script writing to a file with git command, and double quotes

Tags: git, batch-file

I got the following batch script in-cooperate a git call:

```
@echo off
ECHO ^" > test.txt
ECHO &call git describe >> test.txt
ECHO ^" >> test.txt
```

What I really want is to have

```
"theGitDescribeContent"
```

in the test.txt file.

But what I really get from the batch srcipt is

```
"
theGitDescribeContent
"
```

I have looked up a few sites about how to write to a file without the newline but it does't work out. e.g.

```
echo|set /p="^"" > test.log
echo|set /p=&call git describe >> test.log
echo|set /p="^"" >> test.log
```

It looks like it does not like

```
echo|set /p="^"" > test.log
```

from the first place as it does not store anything in test.log and

```
echo|set /p=&call git describe >> test.log
```

produces

```
theGitDescribeContent


//a new line after the content above
```

This should be really simple but it already took me an hour to try and to look for solutions online.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `echo|set /p="^"" > test.log` does not work, because the `^` appears in between `""`, so it is not evaluated, and then you have unbalanced quotes; use `set /P =^""" < nul > test.log` instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a batch sript:

```
@echo off
set "tag="
for /f %%i in ('git describe') do set "tag=%%i"
echo "%tag%"> test.txt
```

If you run in the command line, use `%i` insetad of `%%i`.

As @aschipfl commentted, the answer needs update, from `echo ^"%tag%^" > test.txt` to `echo "%tag%"> test.txt`, adding double quotations around `var=value`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works perfectly! Beside that, I would want to know what exactly what technique you used here, do you have any suggestion on top of your head where I can read more about this?

Comment: @J.Chen I just googled `how to assign the output to a variable in batch`. You will see different methods. As for the details, you may need to read some tutorials on batch scripting.

Comment: Why escaping the quotes here (`^"`)? it's not necessary. You should remove the space in front of `>` or write `> test.txt echo "%tag%"` to avoid a trailing space to be output also...

Comment: You're welcome! Finally, let me recommend to use the quoted `set` syntax like `set "VAR=Value"` to avoid trouble with special characters and to avoid unintended (invisible) trailing spaces...